# triple nested for loops in python to update pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have honestly tried all possible solutions, I think I am nearly there but still something is not working
I have a dataframe with coin names and their tags.

| coin | tags |
| --- | --- |
| bitcoin | [mineable, pow, sha-256, store-of-value, state-channels] |

I want to extract the tags in a binary dataframe. Like that

| coin | mineable | Sha 256 | scrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bitcoin | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| dogecoin | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I have prepared a dataframe like that

| coin | mineable | Sha 256 | scrypt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bitcoin | mineable | Sha 256 | scrypt |
| dogecoin | mineable | Sha 256 | scrypt |

the idea was when I run the loop if it finds the the tags in the list it changes it to 1 and when it does not it leaves it (or even better it changes to 0)

```
for index_tags, row2 in tag_df2.iterrows():#final data set to be changed
  for index, row in tags_head.iterrows():#dataset with the tags and the coin names
    for my_tags in clean_set: #unique list of tags
      if my_tags in (row['tags']): 
        print ('-----coin name-------------------->>>>',(row['name']))  
        print (my_tags)      
        tag_df2.loc[index_tags, my_tags]=1
```

Now it seems it works iterating through everything but it only finds the first values for the bitcoins and it copies the same to all coins. I add a link to my colab notebook too.
When I print it seems going through the data no problem but when I try to update the dataframe it just copies one to all coins. I hope someone can help me.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sn5lwqiNicoBy2L00EZNmhLgz_SBxsOg?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_dummies`:

```
# After you have generated `tags` DataFrame with
# tags = df_new[['name','tags']]

pd.get_dummies(tags.set_index('name')['tags'].explode()).sum(level=0)
```

Output (only showing the first 3 columns here to illustrate the result):

```
                         1confirmation-portfolio  a16z-portfolio  ai-big-data  \
name                                                                            
bitcoin                                        1               1            0   
ethereum                                       1               1            0   
binance coin                                   0               0            0   
dogecoin                                       0               0            0   
cardano                                        0               0            0   
...                                          ...             ...          ...   
australian dollar token                        0               0            0   
chia network                                   0               0            0   
safemars                                       0               0            0   
lendhub                                        0               0            0   
3x long bitcoin token                          0               0            0
```

Comment: thank you! I have been working on this for days and you did in one line of code, pretty amazing

Comment: Cool, happy that it helped! Can you please accept the answer if everything works as expected?

Comment: I have upped your answer but I don't have enough reputation for doing it. Thank you again!